# Image Set Width Height Attributes in HTML, Set Width 100% in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an image whose size I know.

```
<img class="example" src="img.jpg" width="1024" height="768" />
```

I want to have the width and height attributes set so it can layout where the image will be **before it's downloaded**. The image may take a second or two to come in, so when it does, I don't want the page to suddenly jump.

However, I also want the image to have `width: 100%`. Is there a way to achieve this using CSS?

I tried

```
.example {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

However, this ignores the aspect ratio I specified in the HTML. Is there a way I can use the width and height attributes defined in the HTML to keep the aspect ratio, but have the image to have `width: 100%` (i.e. the width of the parent)?

I don't want to use JS to achieve this, I don't want to hard code the proportions in CSS, and I'd rather not do any margin/padding hacks to achieve this.

**Edit**

Really, I'm just seeing if there's a better way of doing it than this,

https://jsfiddle.net/s6gkonbh/

Comment: You cant set <img> width and height from css. you need to set it inline.

Comment: You can set img width of 100%, but where you actually want that. You want to set its width and height automatically for some div or on viewport, where ? I didn't get that.

Comment: You can use the padding-bottom hack if you know the ratio of image beforehand.

Comment: Yea, that's what I used in my example. It is obviously a massive hack though.

Answer (score 1):

[Update: updated link to fix broken external image url]

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7y38ej9f/)

```
<div style="width:356px; height:452px; background-color:yellow">
<img class="example" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/1427/1370476027_aaf0621679.jpg" width="100%" />
</div>
```

---

just provide the **width and height to the parent container** division which will occupy the space of the image's dimensions while the image will load.

and **set the width of the image to 100%** and it will take height according to aspect ratio. Just set the background color of your parent div to white or something to blend with the background.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7rmgv70b/)

---

**HTML:**

```
<div style="width:500px; height:300px; background-color:yellow">
  <img class="example" src="http://www.finnchat.com/app/uploads/2015/10/Blogi44_metakuva.jpg" width="100%" />
</div>
```

NB: image copyrights are with their respective owners.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try this  remove the height and width from img tag

```
<img class="example" src="img.jpg" />
```

and css

```
.example {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: This will set the height to 100% of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is by using javascript. Just set width 100% in css, then with javascript get the imatge width an multiply by the aspect ratio to get the desired height.